# Does GnuPG check for revocation certificates on keyserver automaticaly?

Tags: key-management, pgp, gnupg, certificate-revocation, openpgp

If a key was revoked, I may not know if the revocation key was published just after I downloaded the key with `gpg --recv-key`.

Does GnuPG grant that it is up to date before using a key? Or do I need to run `gpg --refresh-keys` every time I encrypt of verify a signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GnuPG does not automatically fetch or refresh keys when using them. You should update your keyring regularly and on occasion, especially if you fear revoked keys.

For this reason, it is reasonable to notify known users of your key when revoking it.